# What is the procedure for addition and removal of capabilities in docker?

Tags: docker

I need to enable some more capabilities other than the one provided by default. Docker documentation says it is possible to modify using a non-default profile. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent versions of `docker` support the `--cap-add` and `--cap-drop` flags to `docker run`.  These let you modify the capability set available to a container when it starts.